# How do I execute a long-running routine based on a timed database poll in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, queue

I have a routine that polls a database to look for work, and if it finds work there, it should execute it. It can only execute 1 (one) work order at a time, and this work-order could take anywhere from 5 seconds to several minutes to run. During this time it should not poll the database for more work, but wait until the current work is done.

I was thinking of using `setTimeout` to accomplish this, by doing the work in the timeout-event, and setting a new timeout at the end of the function. But I don't know if this is the best way to do it. Is there a "best practice" for these things?

Answer (score 0):

It's an ok way! Some code, maybe that helps:

```
(function poll () {
    fetchJob(onJob);

    function onJob (err, job) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (job) return execute(job, poll);
        setTimeout(poll, 1000);
    }

}());
```